# Online seminars

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

In the time of COVID-19 everything went online including seminars. A good thing about online seminars is that they can be attended by everyone and many seminars that I attended had more than 50 participants, an unthinkable number for a regular seminar.

However, the number of online seminars is only a fraction of the regular seminars that used to be in the time before pandemic and I have hard time to see what is out there (I am particularly interested in analysis seminars, but the question is open to all kinds of seminars).

> **Question.** Do you know what online seminars are currently running?

Please include the link and a description of the seminar like for example "Analysis and PDE" plus any other relevant information.

In my department there is a [Geometric Analysis Seminar](http://www.mathematics.pitt.edu/seminar-colloquia/geometric-analysis-seminar). This is in fact an international seminar.

Comment: Look at https://researchseminars.org/.

Comment: Any reason to advertise a particular platform in the title?

Comment: @YCor You are right. No need. I just took Zoom for granted. Mea culpa!

Comment: just to explain the closure: the pointer to "researchseminars.org" is the top-voted answer in the earlier question, hence this was marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker No complains on my side. I just did not see the other post.

Comment: This is rather a curious question, there are as many seminars to attend at the moment as one could wish for and it's time management which is the enemy.

Comment: @HollisWilliams That is correct, but what I noticed, many seminars that used to run do not run any longer. On the other hand now we have access to all seminars wherever they are.